# What's the result and parsed result of the expression j+=j-=j*j and j+=j*=j-=j? (multiple equals)

Tags: java

Is this expression parsed from left to right? I'm trying to explain the parsed result but the last result is wrong.

```
int j=10, k=10; 
j+=j-=j*=j;   //j=j+(j-=j*=j)=j+(j-j*j)
k+=k*=k-=k;   //k=k+k*k-k;
System.out.println(j+";"+k);
```

Comment: *But the last result is wrong.* Or rather you just think it is wrong

Comment: I have run the result is -80 and 10.But  my result is -80 and 100 according to my parse result.

Comment: Treat expressions such as these like drugs: "Just say NO!"

Comment: @KevinAnderson,Yes,I was asked from an interview,It is difficult to understand.

Comment: @Aominè,OK,I will install and try later,Thank you.

Comment: If they don't hire you for not knowing this crap--or more importantly for knowing enough to say "This is crap and should never be used"--you didn't want to work there anyway :-)

Comment: Most of the time if they throw you a curve ball like this, showing them your train of thought on how to come up with an answer is arguably as important as providing them with the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignments are parsed from right to left. The way you've expressed

```
j+=j-=j*=j;
```

as

```
j=j+(j-j*j);
```

is correct, but the order of operations might be better expressed by:

```
j=j+(j-(j*j)));
```

Similarly, you can rewrite the assignment involving k as:

```
k=k+(k*(k-k));
```

-80 and 10 are the correct answers, respectively.

Comment: The assignments are parsed from right to left. or left to right?Is it regular?

Comment: I'll use k+=k*=k-=k as an example. First, k-=k is evaluated, the rightmost assignment, is evaluated. Then, the evaluation continues moving to the left

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to provide a little more clarity on what exactly happens with the variables through each step.

Keep in mind the result is parsed from right to left.

```
  int j=10, k=10;

  j += j -= j *= j;
//          j *= j   ---> j = 10*10 = 100
//j += j -= 100
//     j -= 100      ---> j = 10-100 = -90
//j += -90           ---> j = 10+(-90) = -80
//j = -80

  k += k *= k -= k;
//          k -= k   ---> k = 10-10 = 0
//k += k *= 0
//     k *= 0        ---> k = 10*0 = 0
//k += 0             ---> k = 10+0 = 10
//k = 10

  System.out.println(j+";"+k); //Prints -80;10
```